# Integrate function is not giving answer

Tags: numerical-integration

```
Integrate[((3.4641 (0.866025 + 
   r (-0.288675 + Sqrt[1 - 2/r + 0.01 r^2])))/(r^3 Sqrt[
 1 - 2/r + 0.01 r^2] \[Omega])),{r,a,b}]
```

This is not giving the answer. Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Usually when this happens, it means that there is no closed form solution for the integral. Have you tried plotting the function to get a general feel for it? Have you tried `NIntegrate` so far?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a quick observation. Your integrand is not defined over some range, as can be seen by this plot

```
integrand = ((3.4641 (0.866025 + 
        r (-0.288675 + Sqrt[1 - 2/r + 0.01 r^2])))/(r^3 Sqrt[
       1 - 2/r + 0.01 r^2] w)) // Rationalize
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[integrand /. w -> 1, {r, -5, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So to help Mathematica, tell it where the `a` and `b` are to avoid the problem area. Mathematica can do the indefinite integral OK

```
anti = Integrate[integrand, r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which gives one the clue the problem is with the limits given.

```
anti = Integrate[integrand, {r, a, b}, Assumptions -> {a > 2, b > a}, 
  GenerateConditions -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to numerical:

```
 anti /. {w -> 1, a -> 3, b -> 5} // N
 (* 0.429391*)
```

And

```
 NIntegrate[integrand /. w -> 1, {r, 3, 5}]

 (* 0.429391 *)
```

Comment: yes. Now it is working. Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to get the following function in terms of d,w using the same method. I am not getting the solution. Integrate[((Sqrt[3] d (d + ([Pi]^(-d/2) r^-d (((2.309/1000) - (1154/1000) d) [Pi]^(d/2) r^ d + ((-25719/1000) + (25719/1000) d) r^3 Gamma[ 1/2 (-1 + d)]))/((-2 + d) Sqrt[ 1 + (3 r^2)/(50 (2 - 3 d + d^2)) - ( 8 [Pi]^(3/2 - d/2) r^(3 - d) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + d)])/(-2 + d)])))/(8 r^2 [Omega])), {r,a,b}]

Answer (score 2):

```
integrand = ((3.4641 (0.866025 + 
          r (-0.288675 + Sqrt[1 - 2/r + 0.01 r^2])))/(r^3 Sqrt[
         1 - 2/r + 0.01 r^2] ω)) // Rationalize // Simplify;

(integral = Assuming[b > a,
    Integrate[integrand, {r, a, b},
      GenerateConditions -> True] //
     Simplify]) // InputForm

(* ConditionalExpression[
 (34641*((400000 - 11547*
       Sqrt[100 - 200/a + a^2])*b + 
    a*(-400000 + 11547*Sqrt[100 - 200/b + 
         b^2])))/(4000000000*
   a*b*ω), b < 0 || 
  a > Root[-200 + 100*#1 + #1^3 & , 1, 0]] *)
```

The conditions are

```
integral[[-1]] /. x_Root :> N[x]

(* b < 0 || a > 1.9283 *)
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the following function in terms of d,w using the same method. I am not getting the solution. Integrate[((Sqrt[3] d (d + (\[Pi]^(-d/2)
      r^-d (((2.309/1000) - (1154/1000) d) \[Pi]^(d/2) r^
        d + ((-25719/1000) + (25719/1000) d) r^3 Gamma[
         1/2 (-1 + d)]))/((-2 + d) Sqrt[
     1 + (3 r^2)/(50 (2 - 3 d + d^2)) - (
      8 \[Pi]^(3/2 - d/2) r^(3 - d) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + d)])/(-2 + 
       d)])))/(8 r^2 \[Omega])), {r,a,b}]

Comment: Not that I can tell. Recommend that you post a new question so that the community can look at it.